# UNIX: How to search and copy all files with the same name to a different directory

Tags: bash, unix, ssh

I thought I would put this out here to help anyone else who may need it.

I had a file, named spreadsheet.csv, that was in 500 different locations on my server. After a bunch of trial and errors, I nailed down this solution to copy every instance of this file, rename it (by increment) and copy it into a different folder.

Hope this helps someone!

```
COUNTER=0; 
for f in $(find folder/ -name 'spreadsheet.csv'); 
do 
  cp -v $f /new/location/spreadsheet$COUNTER.csv; 
  COUNTER=$[$COUNTER+1]; 
done
```

Comment: Please follow the format of this website. Pose the problem in the question, then provide the answer below.

Comment: Note that the Bash `$[…arithmetic…]` notation is deprecated in favour of `$((…arithmetic…))` or `((…arithmetic…))` — see [arithmetic expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Arithmetic-Expansion).  The `$[…]` with single square brackets is  not documented any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple `bash` `for-loop` could achieve this:-

```
COUNTER="0"
fileName="spreadsheet.csv"
for file in $(find folder/ -name "$fileName" -type f -printf '%P\n'); 
do
  sourcePath=$(dirname $(readlink -f "$file")) 
  cp -v $sourcePath/$fileName /new/location/"$fileName$COUNTER" 
  COUNTER=$((COUNTER+1)) 
done
```

The crucial part of the script is getting the source path of each of the files, which I am achieving through `readlink` and `dirname`. Refer their `man` pages to know more about their description.

Example:-

```
$ find . -name "spreadsheet.csv" -type f
./foo/spreadsheet.csv
./bar/spreadsheet.csv
./woo/spreadsheet.csv
./spreadsheet.csv

 $ ./script.sh
`/home/dude/foo/spreadsheet.csv' -> `/new/location/spreadsheet.csv0'
`/home/dude/bar/spreadsheet.csv' -> `/new/location/spreadsheet.csv1'
`/home/dude/woo/spreadsheet.csv' -> `/new/location/spreadsheet.csv2'
`/home/dude/spreadsheet.csv' -> `/new/location/spreadsheet.csv3'
```

Comment: space chars or other special chars in directory names are going to break this: `mkdir foo\ bar ; touch foo\ bar/speadsheet.csv`

Comment: I'm puzzled about the special case coding for symlinks.  Why is it necessary?  When you access the symlink with `cp`, it will make a copy of the file at the end of the symlink, not copy the symlink information.  So, using `readlink` and `dirname` seems like overkill — the system will handle that automatically without any further ado (so `cp -v "$file" "$new_location/$fileName$COUNTER.csv"` would work well as long as you change `fileName` to just `'spreadsheet'` since the number needs to come before the `.csv` extension).

Answer (score 0):

The script is going to break, if there is a space or special char in at least one directory name.

[Inian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5291015/inian) is right about [symlinks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37420076/) too.

There is below a safe and standard solution where only regular files are searched:

```
find folder/ -type f -name 'spreadsheet.csv' -printf "%p\0" | xargs -0 sh -c '
  newlocdir=/new/location;
  COUNTER=$(ls -1 "${newlocdir}"/spreadsheet*.csv 2>/dev/null | awk "END {print NR}") ;
  for f ; do
    cp -v "${f}" "${newlocdir}"/spreadsheet$COUNTER.csv;
    COUNTER=$(($COUNTER+1));
  done' dummyarg0
```

`-printf "%p\0"` prints pathname of the files found with an additional NULL.

`xargs -0` is able to read the files found and consider NULL char as separator between entries.

`| awk "END {print NR}"` prints the number of lines reads from the pipeline.

`COUNTER=$(ls -1 "${newlocdir}"/spreadsheet*.csv 2>/dev/null | awk "END {print NR}")` stores the number of `spreadsheet*.csv` files already present in the new location, into COUNTER variable.

`for f ; do` reads the positional parameters; the filenames provided by `xargs`.

`sh -c ' .... ' dummyarg0` make `sh` execute the commands provided. `dummyarg0` is a mandatory first parameter. `sh` sets the value of special parameter 0 to `dummyarg0` (unused).

The test:

```
$ find folder/
folder/
folder/dir2
folder/dir2/spreadsheet.csv
folder/foo bar
folder/foo bar/spreadsheet.csv
folder/spreadsheet.csv
folder/tr"uc
folder/tr"uc/spreadsheet.csv
folder/fo'o
folder/fo'o/spreadsheet.csv
folder/dir1
folder/dir1/spreadsheet.csv
$ find folder/ -type f -name 'spreadsheet.csv' -printf "%p\0" | xargs -0 sh -c '
  newlocdir=.;
  COUNTER=$(ls -1 "${newlocdir}"/spreadsheet*.csv 2>/dev/null | awk "END {print NR}") ;
  for f ; do
    cp -v "${f}" "${newlocdir}"/spreadsheet$COUNTER.csv;
    COUNTER=$(($COUNTER+1));
  done' dummyarg0
`folder/dir2/spreadsheet.csv' -> `./spreadsheet0.csv'
`folder/foo bar/spreadsheet.csv' -> `./spreadsheet1.csv'
`folder/spreadsheet.csv' -> `./spreadsheet2.csv'
`folder/tr"uc/spreadsheet.csv' -> `./spreadsheet3.csv'
`folder/fo\'o/spreadsheet.csv' -> `./spreadsheet4.csv'
`folder/dir1/spreadsheet.csv' -> `./spreadsheet5.csv'
```